# .NET Xsl script transform results in 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, scripting, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

XSL noobie but uttery stuck!

I have a transform that formats a date using c# scripting function , this works fine when I am in VS 2008 and run "show xml output", the output is exactly what I want.

However , when i try to run this using code I get the error

> Predefined type 'System.Object' is not
>   defined or imported

To function to call the transform looks like this , it's pretty basic and worked before I started to use scripting

> ```
> public static string RunXSLT(string xsltFile, string inputXML)
> {
>
>     XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
>     XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
>     settings.EnableScript = true;
>
>     transform.Load(xsltFile, settings, null);
>
>     StringReader sReader = new StringReader(inputXML);
>     XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(sReader);
>
>     //Create an XmlTextWriter which outputs to memory stream
>     Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
>     XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream,> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
>
>
>     transform.Transform(xmlTextReader, xmlWriter);
>
>     stream.Position = 0;
>
>     XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
>     XmlDoc.Load(stream);
>
>     return XmlDoc.OuterXml;
>   }
> ```

The XSL transform is this..

> ```
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
>             xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>             xmlns:nlbExtension="urn:nlbExtension"
>             exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl nlbExtension">
>
> <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
>
> <msxsl:script implements-prefix="nlbExtension" language="C#">    
> <![CDATA[
>   public string FormatDateTime(string xsdDateTime, string format)
>   {
>       DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(xsdDateTime);
>
>       return date.ToString(format); 
>    }
> ]]>
> </msxsl:script>
>
> <xsl:template match="/">
> <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
>   http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" 
>   xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
>
>   <xsl:for-each select="./Collection/Content" >
>     <url>
>       <loc>http://www.nlb.org<xsl:value-of select="./QuickLink/text()"/></loc>
>       <lastmod><xsl:value-of select="./DateModified/text()" /></lastmod>
>     </url>
>   </xsl:for-each>      
> </urlset>
> </xsl:template>
> </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```

Comment: For info, an xsd datetime would work better (IMO) with `XmlConvert.ToDateTime`.

Comment: Missing a `>` on `<urlset` - is that just a typo? It makes we cautious as to what else may be copy/paste error...

Answer (score 4):

I know this issue is very old, but maybe this helps someone who is searching for this problem.

I currently became the same **compiling** error but in totally different topic of C# programming.

I am using Sharp Develop 4.2 and had the same issue. For me the solution was to ***add 
"mscorlib" to the references of the project.***

This error is a known issue of Microsoft, but dont know the current situation. Just found some discussions from 2010.

Somehow this reference was missing and i do not completely understand at the moment why other projects of me are working without explicit reference to mscorlib, but maybe this indeed is the bug itself ;-)

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: I tried adding mscorlib to the references of the project and it did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce (indeed, you don't actually use the extension in your xslt). I tested it, adding (to the xslt):

```
<xsl:value-of select="nlbExtension:FormatDateTime(.,'dd MMM yyyy')"/>
```

and using the input xml:

```
string xml = new XElement("xml", DateTime.Now).ToString();
```

And it worked fine (I changed to `XmlConvert.ToDateTime` to match xsd format, but it worked OK either way).

If there is a problem, it is in code that you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler example , (sorry about typo) , again this works in VS2008 just running the XML against the style sheet but using the C# code I get

> Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Code

> ```
> public void RunFileXSLT()
> {
>     // Open books.xml as an XPathDocument.
>     XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("c:\\temp\\raw.xml");
>
>     // Create a writer for writing the transformed file.
>     XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("c:\\temp\\OutputTest.xml");
>
>     // Create and load the transform with script execution enabled.
>     XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
>     XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
>     settings.EnableScript = true;
>     transform.Load("c:\\temp\\Simple.xslt", settings, null);
>
>     // Execute the transformation.
>     transform.Transform(doc, writer);
> }
> ```

the xml is this

> ```
> <xml>
>   <item>
>      <date>11/11/2009</date>
>   </item>
>   <item>
>    <date>11/11/2009</date>
>   </item>
> </xml>
> ```

the transform is this

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
>
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
>             xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>             xmlns:nlbExtension="urn:nlbExtension"
>             exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl nlbExtension">
>                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
>
>
>              <msxsl:script implements-prefix="nlbExtension" language="C#">    
> <![CDATA[
>   public string FormatDateTime(string xsdDateTime, string format)
>   {
>       DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(xsdDateTime);
>
>       return date.ToString(format); 
>    }
> ]]>   </msxsl:script>
>
>
> <xsl:template match="/">
>    <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
>        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
>       xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" >
>   <xsl:for-each select="./xml/item" >
>     <url>
>       <loc>http://www.a-website.com</loc>
>       <lastmod>
>         <xsl:value-of select="nlbExtension:FormatDateTime(./date,'s')"/>
>       </lastmod>
>     </url>
>   </xsl:for-each>      
> </urlset>
> ```

Comment: Works fine for me: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><url><loc>http://www.a-website.com</loc><lastmod>2009-11-11T00:00:00</lastmod></url><url><loc>http://www.a-website.com</loc><lastmod>2009-11-11T00:00:00</lastmod></url></urlset>`

Comment: hmm crikey , I wonder what the problem is then. The XSL looks right and the .NET is pretty much cut-paste from MSDN example ,
.net installation problem?? Grasping at straws here